# Http GET request to Apache solr with umlauts from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, solr, http-get

I'm trying to make request with umlauts in URL parameters to get recommendations:

```
function getRecommendations(auth, callback) {

    var params = '+"olivenöl"';
    var host = 'something.com';
    var path = "/solr/cloud/select?q=*&fq=ingredient_t:(" + params + ")";

    var options = {
        "host": host,
        "path": path,
        "method": 'GET',
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": auth,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        }
    };

    http.request(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function (d) {
            body += d;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            callback(body);
        });

    });
}
```

Response has empty list of recommendations in a case if German umlauts present in URL params.

I tried to encode as ö => oe or ü => ue... but than system skip parameters as not existing.

Does someone know how to encode UMLAUTS? I also confused is this HTTP GET issue or Solr issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it will be a good idea to use `encodeURIComponent(path)`. Please refer to this link for further information https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every case I suggest to encode the parameters passed in query string using `encodeURIComponent()` function.

But I also suggest to test that your Solr instance is properly configured to handle queries with UMLAUTS special characters.

You can do this directly with you browser, for example executing a query with UMLAUTS special characters.

So that we can exclude that is a problem related to your Solr configuration but it's in your node.js request implementation.

Just another thing, just double check if Solr to returns json. And if you want be sure of that add the `wt=json` parameter at your query.

```
var ingredient = encodeURIComponent(params);
var path = "/solr/cloud/select?q=*&wt=json&fq=ingredient_t:(" + ingredient + ")";
```